# Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Signup)"

Tags: reactjs, redux

Am new in reactjs and am developing a small signup functionality with react-redux but am facing this error. I was following a certain tutorial but it seems am stuck right now

[image]

Below is my code :

**Signup.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  NavBar from './subcomponents/NavBar'
import SignUpForm from './subcomponents/SignUpForm'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {userSignUpRequest} from "./actions/signUpActions";

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Signup extends Component {

    render() {

        const {userSignUpRequest} = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar/>
                <SignUpForm userSignUpRequest={userSignUpRequest}/>

            </div>

        );
    }
}

Signup.propTypes = {

    userSignUpRequest: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(null, { userSignUpRequest })(Signup);
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './redux-js/index';
 import App from "./App";
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";


const store = createStore(
    (state = {})  => state,
     applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

ReactDOM.render(
     <provider store={store}>
         <App />
     </provider>
         , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error**

> Could not find "store" in either the context or props of
>   "Connect(Signup)". **Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`**, or
>   explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Signup)"

**Solution**

You need to import the **Provider** in your `index.js` file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './redux-js/index';
import App from "./App";
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; //added

const store = createStore(
    (state = {})  => state,
     applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

ReactDOM.render(
     <Provider store={store}>   //fixed typo
         <App />
     </Provider >
         , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `App` component with `Provider` component imported from `'react-redux'`

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
     <Provider store={store}>
         <App />
     </Provider>
         , document.getElementById('root'));
```